# For which operads $O$ does $\operatorname{coAlg}_O(C) = C$ whenever $C$ is cartesian monoidal?

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory, operads

Let $O$ be an operad, and let $D$ be a symmetric monoidal category. Then there is a forgetful functor $\operatorname{Alg}_O(D) \to D$. This functor is an equivalence in either of the following cases:

1. If $D$ is cocartesian monoidal and $O = E_\infty$;
2. If $D$ is cocartesian monoidal and $O = E_1$.

**Question:** For which operads $O$ does the statement

> For all cocartesian monoidal $D$, the forgetful functor $\operatorname{Alg}_O(D) \to D$ is an equivalence.

hold?

**Notes:**

- If $D$ is cocartesian monoidal, we have $D = \operatorname{Alg}_{E_\infty}(D)$, so that $\operatorname{Alg}_O(D) = \operatorname{Alg}_O(\operatorname{Alg}_{E_\infty}(D)) = \operatorname{Alg}_{O \otimes E_\infty}(D)$. So a sufficient condition is that the Boardman-Vogt tensor product have $O \otimes E_\infty = E_\infty$. By [a theorem of Schlank and Yanovski](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/algebraic-and-geometric-topology/volume-19/issue-6/The-inftycategorical-EckmannHilton-argument/10.2140/agt.2019.19.3119.short), this holds whenever $O$ is reduced, i.e. $O$ is single-colored and $O(0) = O(1) = \ast$.

This covers a great many examples, but maybe it's true even more generally? And I'd be interested to understand the case of enriched operads as well.

Comment: I'm slightly confused by your use of the $E_\infty$ operad and not simply the "commutative" operad and the reference you cite. Is $D$ intended to be an $\infty$-category ? Otherwise I don't quite understand what you mean. At least one example not covered by the result you cite would be any operads with $O(1)=*$ and $O(i) = \emptyset$ for all $i >1$ , but with $O(0)$ arbitrary.

Comment: Oh sure -- I suppose I'm using an "implicit $\infty$" convention.

Comment: I think the condition $E_\infty \otimes O \simeq E_\infty$ you are proposing is also necessary. In fact, it seems that two operads have the same co-algebras in all cartesian categories if and only if $E_\infty \otimes O \simeq E_\infty \otimes O'$. But I don't know if there is a way to rephrase it in a more practical way.

Comment: The idea being that, at least for 1-categories, the category of $E_\infty$-coalgebra is cartesian monoidal and model of $E_\infty \otimes O$ are models of $O$ in this cartesian monoidal category... I'm not sure if this sort of thing has been developed for $\infty$-categories though.

Comment: (By "model" I meant coalgebras)

Comment: @SimonHenry Oh sure -- if $Alg_O(D) = Alg_{O'}(D)$ for all cocartesian monoidal $D$, naturally in $D$, then $Alg_O(Alg_{E_\infty}(D)) = Alg_{O'}(Alg_{E_\infty}(D))$, naturally in $D$. That is, $Alg_{O \otimes E_\infty}(D) = Alg_{O \otimes E\infty}(D)$, naturally in $D$. By Yoneda, this implies that $O \otimes E_\infty = O' \otimes E_\infty$.